# Clear everything on page after three seconds

Tags: html, css

For my project, I'm trying to have it so the page clears after displaying something for 3 seconds, and then shows something new after the clear. Here is my code:

```
<style media="screen">
      body {
        background-color: black;
      }
      p {
        color: white;
        font-family: "Courier";
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 300px 0 0 250px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 30em;
        animation: type 4s steps(60, end);
      }


      @keyframes type{
        from { width: 0; }
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Welcome...</p>
    <!--- I want the page to clear here, to display the second paragraph --->
    <p>Are you ready to pass the gates?</p>
```

I have tried many alternatives, but nothing has worked.

I hope I made myself clear and that you can help me.

Comment: So you want to show one `<p>` element at a time, three seconds for each `<p>`? What should happen after the last `<p>` has been on screen for three seconds? Should it remain visible on screen, should it fade out, or should the cycle start over again? Please: take a moment to read the "*[ask]*" guidance, then [edit] your question to include the answers to these questions in order that others can read, and understand, the question. (especially because comments are transitory).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
 setTimeout(
    function() {
      document.getElementById('one').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('two').style.display='block';
    }, 3000);
```

```css
#two{
display:none;}
```

```html
<p id = 'one'>Welcome!</p>
<p id = 'two'>goodBy</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved my life!! lol you are so awesome!

Comment: I've down-voted the question because you've explained nothing about your code and the question is tagged with [tag:html] and [tag:css], notably lacking a [tag:javascript] tag.

Comment: With all due respect to your 235,000 plus points (wow) the solution provided is self explanatory.  It's short and sweet.  While there may be another solution with just CSS using the transition property, I believe this is the preferred approach.  You are of course welcome to add a better answer.

Comment: @DCR: thank you. I dislike guessing at what the OP wants, hence my comment to the question, asking for an edit to include details. This is one of those things for which I do think JavaScript is best-suited, but it's not tagged so I interpret that as being not desired/preferred (though the OP has since accepted regardless). The code is simple, and largely obvious from minimal exposure, but for others to learn I have a strong preference for actual code explanation (look at some of my answers for how strongly I believe in that). I'm trying to prompt improvement, but it's a personal choice.